# Is the number of words finite, when you don't know how to count?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

This question is inspired by this one:

[Can you do math without knowing how to count?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390427/can-you-do-math-without-knowing-how-to-count)

Let $M_2$ be the set of words constructed by concatenation of the letters $a_1$ and $a_2$, with :

(*) : for any $x$ word of $M_2$ $xx = x$.

Is it true $card(M_2)=card(\mathbb N) $?

If not, is it true $\exists n \in \mathbb N, card(M_n)=card(\mathbb N) $?

The condition (*) comes from the hypothesis that we assume that we do not know how to count.

Comment: Sorry, just to get your (*) condition: what you mean is that you identify also subwords? I mean: $abbc$ and $abc$ are the same word for every $a,b,c\in M_2$?

Comment: Yes................

Comment: Doesn't it follow that the only six elements of $M_2$ are $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_1a_2$, $a_2a_1$, $a_2a_1a_2$ and $a_1a_2a_1$?

Comment: For $n\ge 3$ there are infinitely many square-free words. See this (and references therein) : https://oeis.org/A006156.

Comment: @shan why?. '...

Comment: Take any element of $M_2$, write it using as few letters as possible using (*). If it has length $\geq 4$, its initial subword of length three must be one of the words I've listed above. But then there must be a reduction when one of these words is concatenated with a further $a_1$ or $a_2$: e.g. $(a_1a_2a_1)a_2=(a_1a_2)(a_1a_2)=a_1a_2$.

Comment: Thanks. @A.DellaCorte 
Is there an algorithm to enumerate an infinity set of distincts ternary words square free?

Comment: @Dattier See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word#Infinite_squarefree_words)

Comment: Thanks. Well, even if we don't know how to count, we can have an infinite number of symbols.

Comment: This flavour of problem (at least more general forms) seems to be a restricted version of the Burnside problem for semigroups.

Comment: There are uncountably many squarefree ternary words (of infinite length) $x_1 x_2 \cdots$. In fact, let $w=x_1x_2\cdots$ be a word in the four symbols $0,1,2,*$, such that no matter how we replace each $*$ with either 0, 1, or 2, a squarefree word results. Then the maximum possible density of the $*$'s is exactly $3/16$. See https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0129054118420078.

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, even though there are infinitely many square-free words on three letters, the assumption that $xx=x$ for all words $x$ still reduces them to finitely many. I don't have the reference handy, but here's an example of what's involved. $abcbabc=abcbabcbc=abcbc=abc$ even though both $abcbabc$ and $abc$ are square-free. (In fancy language:The variety of idempotent semigroups is locally finite.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass What about the second question? Can you give a justification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm upgrading my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390668/is-the-number-of-words-finite-when-you-dont-know-how-to-count#comment995922_390668) to an answer, because I've found the source for the result asserted in the comment: For every $n$, the semigroup $M_n$, presented by $n$ generators subject to the relations $xx=x$ for all words $x$, is finite.  The reference is

Green, J. A.; Rees, D.
[On semi-groups in which x^r=x](https://doi.org/10.1017/s0305004100027341).
Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 48 (1952), 35–40,

and its Mathematical Reviews number is [MR0046353](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=46353).

Comment: Note for other readers: semigroups in which every element is idempotent are often called *bands*. A proof of this result of Green and Rees, along with some of the other basic theory of bands, can be found in Howie's *Introduction To Semigroup Theory*